# Customize Lightning Carousel in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, images

I'm trying to remove the "Description" from carousel, want to diplay only the image. Is it possible? I'm looking for it in documentation but wasn't able to see any information about that. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel-image/documentation

Also need to include arrow navigation, similar to salesforce home page. To do that I have to implement a carousel from scratch?

[image: Carousel]

```
            <lightning-carousel disable-auto-scroll>  
                <template for:each={imgs} for:item="rec" for:index="index">      
                    <lightning-carousel-image
                        key={rec}
                        src={rec}
                        alternative-text="Images">
                    </lightning-carousel-image>
                 </template>         
            </lightning-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the description value and it wont show up. Its an optional attribute. Refer information below. the [same](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel-image/documentation) link you provided has that information.

> For each image, use the src attribute to specify the path to the
> image. Optionally use header and description attributes to provide a
> header and descriptive text that the carousel displays below the
> image. You can also hyperlink the images with the href attribute.

Question 2

> Also need to include arrow navigation, similar to salesforce home
> page. To do that I have to implement a carousel from scratch?

Yes i think it has to be custom.

Comment: But about the first question, even when I remove the description the white space continues.

Comment: Did you remove the attribute from markup itself or just nullified its content

Comment: Yes, I just removed